How to pass values in real time between classes
I'm trying to use the library flet to build a simple app for downloading youtube videos, but I'm also learning Python at the same time.
My problem is that I'm building the components in classes and I need my second class to have real-time access to some data. It loads it in the beginning, but when the values change in the first class it doesn't update on the second one.
I've tried passing the values directly from my page.add() but it worked the same way.
This is my code:
from yt_dlp import YoutubeDL
import flet as ft
import func


class ID_Section(ft.Column):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.horizontal_alignment = ft.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER

        self.valid_id = False

        self.txt_video_id = ft.TextField(
            label='Cole o ID do vídeo/short/playlist aqui...', on_change=self.make_invalid
        )
        self.bt_validate_id = ft.ElevatedButton(text="Validar", on_click=self.validate)
        self.txt_id_status = ft.Text('Insira uma ID para começar!', size=14, color='yellow')

        self.controls = [
            ft.Row([
                self.txt_video_id,
                self.bt_validate_id,
            ],
            ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER
            ),
            self.txt_id_status,
        ]

    def check_id(self, e):
        if self.valid_id:
             self.txt_id_status.value='ID válida!'
             self.txt_id_status.color='green'
        elif self.txt_video_id.value== '':
             self.txt_id_status.value='Insira uma ID para começar!'
             self.txt_id_status.color='yellow'
        else:
             self.txt_id_status.value='Insira uma ID válida!'
             self.txt_id_status.color='red'


    def make_invalid(self, e):
        self.valid_id = False
        self.check_id(e)
        self.update()

    def validate(self, e):
        if self.txt_video_id.value != '':
            self.valid_id = func.link_validation(self.txt_video_id.value)
            self.check_id(e)
            self.update()

class Download_Section(ft.Column):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.horizontal_alignment = ft.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER

        self.valid = ID_Section().valid_id
        self.vid_id = ID_Section().txt_video_id.value

        self.btn_download = ft.CupertinoFilledButton(
            content=ft.Text("Baixar"),
            disabled_color='yellow',
            on_click=self.download_vid
        )

        self.controls = [
            ft.Row(),
            self.btn_download,
        ]

    def download_vid(self, e):
        print(self.valid)
        print(self.vid_id)

def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.title = 'YouTube Downloader'
    page.vertical_alignment = ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER
    page.horizontal_alignment = ft.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER

    valid = ID_Section().valid_id

    page.add(
        ft.Text('YouTube Downloader', size=28),
        ft.Row(height=20),
        ID_Section(),
        Download_Section()
    )

ft.app(main)

The ID_Section class takes in a YouTube ID (video, playlist or short) and validates it. What I want is to be able to have that self.valid_id (a bool) and self.txt_video_id (the id in the textbox) in the second class, Download_Section.
It works when the app starts and it prints the values, but once I change them in the app it stays the same as in the beginning.

You need events and callbacks.  If these are peer controls (not parent/child), then it would normally be up to the parent to handle this.  The parent would hand a callback function to the element generating the event, and the callback would pass the information to the receiving object.

one method is to keep data in list or dict and keep it outside classes - and send this list/dict to both classes - so both will have access to the same values in list/dict. But if one class will change data then other class will need some method to control if there is new data. So simpler it to create function in other class and send it to first class - and first class  has to execute it when it add new data.

don't do valid = ID_Section().valid_id and later page.add(..., ID_Section(), ...) because this creates two separate object - and if you set something in one ID_Section(), then other ID_Section() will doesn't know it. You have to create it only once id_seciton = ID_Section() and later valid = id_seciton.valid_id and page.add(..., id_seciton, ...)

and the same problem can be inside Download_Section - you create many separate ID_Section() and they don't have the same values - you have to create only one instance of class. You should create id_seciton = ID_Section() at start and later send it as parameter to Download_Section(id_seciton) - and then it will have current values from the only existing ID_Section()

Thank you all, after reading through all of it I kindda figured out the mess I made lmao.So the solution that worked for me was changing my main and creating id_section = ID_Section() and download_section = Download_Section(id_section) and then adding them to my page.
Then on the Download_Section I assigned it to self.id_data = id_section, which seems to be working fine so far.

One problem is that you use many times ID_Section() and it creates many separate objects - and when you change value in one object (displayed on screen) then other object (which you have in Download_section) doesn't know it. You have to create only one ID_Section() and use it in all places. And you have to get current value directly from this object without assigning to local variable.
First: create object and use it in add() and send it as parameter in other class(es)
    id_section = ID_Section()     # <-- create object

    valid = id_section.valid_id   # <-- use the same object

    page.add(
        ft.Text('YouTube Downloader', size=28),
        ft.Row(height=20),
        id_section,                   # <-- use the same object
        Download_Section(id_section)  # <-- use the same object
    )

Second: get this object in other class(es), assign to self.id_section and always use it to get current value(s)
class Download_Section(ft.Column):

    def __init__(self, id_section):  # <-- get as parameter
        super().__init__()
        self.horizontal_alignment = ft.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER

        self.id_section = id_section  # <-- keep it

        #self.valid = self.id_section.valid_id             # no need it 
        #self.vid_id = self.id_section.txt_video_id.value  # no need it

        self.btn_download = ft.CupertinoFilledButton(
            content=ft.Text("Baixar"),
            disabled_color='yellow',
            on_click=self.download_vid
        )

        self.controls = [
            ft.Row(),
            self.btn_download,
        ]

    def download_vid(self, e):
        print(self.id_section.valid_id)   # <-- get current value from `id_section`
        print(self.id_section.txt_video_id.value)  # <-- get current value from `id_section`


I came to a solution really close to that after reading the comments. The only difference is that I created a download_section = Download_Section(id_section) and then added it to the page, which seems to be working.
Is there a downside to the way I did it?

there is no difference - it works the same.
